# Can GA4-API fetch the data from requests made with a combination of minute and region and sessions?

Tags: ruby, google-api, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4, google-api-ruby-client

**Problem**

With UA, I was able to get the number of sessions per region per minute (a combination of minute, region, and sessions), but is this not possible with GA4?

If not, is there any plan to support this in the future?

---

**Detail**

I ran [GA4 Query Explorer](https://ga-dev-tools.web.app/ga4/query-explorer/) with date, hour, minute, region in Dimensions and sessions in Metrics.

But I got an incompatibility error.

---

**What I tried**

I have checked with [GA4 Dimensions & Metrics Explorer](https://ga-dev-tools.web.app/ga4/dimensions-metrics-explorer/) and confirmed that the combination of minute and region is not possible. (see image below).

[image: image of the result I checked]

**(updated 2022/05/16 15:35)Checked by Code Execution**

I ran it with ruby.

```
require "google/analytics/data/v1beta/analytics_data"
require 'pp'
require 'json'

ENV['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] = '' # service acount file path
client = ::Google::Analytics::Data::V1beta::AnalyticsData::Client.new

LIMIT_SIZE = 1000
offset = 0

loop do
  request = Google::Analytics::Data::V1beta::RunReportRequest.new(
    property: "properties/xxxxxxxxx",
    date_ranges: [
      { start_date: '2022-04-01', end_date: '2022-04-30'}
    ],
    dimensions: %w(date hour minute region).map { |d| { name: d } },
    metrics: %w(sessions).map { |m| { name: m } },
    keep_empty_rows: false,
    offset: offset,
    limit: LIMIT_SIZE
  )

  ret = client.run_report(request)
  dimension_headers = ret.dimension_headers.map(&:name)
  metric_headers = ret.metric_headers.map(&:name)
  puts (dimension_headers + metric_headers).join(',')
  ret.rows.each do |row|
    puts (row.dimension_values.map(&:value) + row.metric_values.map(&:value)).join(',')
  end

  offset += LIMIT_SIZE

  break if ret.row_count <= offset
end
```

The result was an error.

> 3:The dimensions and metrics are incompatible.. debug_error_string:{"created":"@1652681913.393028000","description":"Error received from peer ipv4:172.217.175.234:443","file":"src/core/lib/surface/call.cc","file_line":953,"grpc_message":"The dimensions and metrics are incompatible.","grpc_status":3}

Comment: Please edit your question and include your code.  I need to see which calls you are making to the api.   Or is this question not programming related?

Comment: @DaImTo
Thanks for your reply. I have edited and added the code and the execution results.

Comment: @DaImTo 
If you don't mind, could you please confirm this?

Answer (score 0):

Error in your code, Make sure you use the actual dimension name and not the UI name. The correct name of that dimension is `dateHourMinute`  not `Date hour and minute`

```
dimensions: %w(dateHourMinute).map { |d| { name: d } },
```

The [query explore](https://ga-dev-tools.web.app/ga4/query-explorer/) returns this request just fine

[image]

results

[image]

## Limited use for region dimension

The as for region.  As the error message states the dimensions and metrics are incompatible.  The issue being that `dateHourMinute` can not be used with region. Switch to `date` or `datehour`

at the time of writing this is a beta api.  I have sent a message off to google to find out if this is working as intended or if it may be changed.

Comment: I can see that it used to work in UA i sent a message off to Google to find out if this is working as intended or if it could be an oversite seeing as this is a beta api.  I will let you know if i hear anything back.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply. I understood.

Comment: Let me know when you receive a message from Google about that problem.
Thank you for everything.

Comment: I got a message back.   It is true that it is incompletable with GA4 at this time but it may change in the future.   They have inquired about your use case.   Can you tell me why you need it?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm glad to hear that. 

Because we provide a web service that uses regional minute data for analysis via UniversalAnalytics.

Comment: As you know, we have to move from UA to GA4 by next year. But we can't do due to such that reason.

Comment: @DalmTo 
I'm sorry , but I forgot to mention your name.